# Facebook takes wrong canonical URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Scenario of the problem:

1. We enforced HTTPS on a website. Any URL with HTTP now redirects (301 permanent redirect) to an appropriate HTTPS URL.
2. To avoid Facebook like/share buttons (that are placed on many pages of the website) loosing previous numbers of likes/shares, we made the buttons to "link" to the old HTTP URLs via the "data-href" property.
3. Additionally we placed the "og:url" meta tag on some pages, pointing to the old HTTP URLs.
4. I then scraped that pages at the Facebook debugger tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to make sure the Facebook gets the fresh data. According to the scraped data, canonical URLs were indeed pointing to the old HTTP URLs just as it should be according to our actions listed above. This was also reflected in the like/share buttons on our pages keeping the old numbers.
5. A few days later I discovered that some pages lose the old numbers of likes/shares. Checking the pages in the Facebook debugger shows that Facebook now takes HTTPS URLs as canonical. We did not make any changes on our pages, and the "og:url" tag is still pointing to the HTTP URLs. But the Facebook wrongly takes HTTPS URLs as canonical URLs. Now if I scrape the information again in the debugger, it agains becomes normal, showing HTTP as canonical and restoring the old number of likes/shares. But obviously it's not a solution to the problem, because we cannot constantly monitor all our pages and scrape them again and again.

Any ideas of what may causing the problem?

Comment: Facebook follows HTTP redirects as well. You need to make your old HTTP URLs available to the scraper, without redirecting it to the HTTPS version. (The scraper can be recognized by its User-Agent, see social plugins FAQ.)

Comment: @CBroe, thanks, I will try it, although it is not said to do so in the [FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#moving-urls)

Comment: Oh yes, the FAQ explicitly mentions this: _“This also requires that the old URL still renders a document with Open Graph tags and returns a HTTP 200 response, at least when loaded by Facebook's crawler. If you want other clients to redirect when they visit the URL, you must send your 301 HTTP response to all non-Facebook crawler clients. The old URL should contain its own og:url tag that points to itself.”_

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, I missed this paragraph when reading the FAQ. I have made an appropriate change to allow the Facebook scrapper to still access the old HTTP URLs. Then I tested both HTTP and HTTPS urls via the debugger tool - both are OK. If you post a full reply to my question then I will be able to set it as an "accepted solution". Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook follows HTTP redirects as well. You need to make your old HTTP URLs available to the scraper, without redirecting it to the HTTPS version. (The scraper can be recognized by its User-Agent, see social plugins FAQ.)

The old HTTP URLs need to be available to the scraper, and not redirected to HTTPS, as the FAQ also mentions:

> “This also requires that the old URL still renders a document with Open Graph tags and returns a HTTP 200 response, at least when loaded by Facebook's crawler. If you want other clients to redirect when they visit the URL, you must send your 301 HTTP response to all non-Facebook crawler clients. The old URL should contain its own og:url tag that points to itself.”